# Pex and Code Contracts

Tags: c#, code-contracts, pex

Below is the code sample from the Pex Documentation pexandcontracts.pdf http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/pexandcontracts.pdf. I realise that this is not a pex specific question, rather it relates to code contracts, but it is code from the pex tutorials.

```
namespace CodeDigging
{
    public class StringExtension
    {
        public static string TrimAfter(string value, string suffix)
        {
            // <pex>
            Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(suffix));
            // </pex>
            Contract.Requires(value != null);
            Contract.Ensures(!Contract.Result<string>().EndsWith(suffix));

            int index = value.IndexOf(suffix);
            if (index < 0)
                return value;                  // (1) First possible contract violation
            return value.Substring(0, index);  // (2) second possible contract violation
        }
    }
}
```

The static verifier provides the following warnings:

CodeContracts: ensures unproven: !Contract.Result().EndsWith(suffix) at point (1) and point (2).

My question is, how would one go about resolving this? As per the pex explorations, there is no possibility of the contract being violated. (... is there?)

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that this is a poor use of Contract.Ensures, as the guarantee is fairly complex and not likely to readily feed into a later Requires.  I would be more inclined to provide assurances of non-nullity and length (i.e. no longer than the original value string.)  The !EndsWith condition should instead be an assertion of the test, which Pex can use to guide its explorations.

Comment: I would tend to agree (thus the reason for my question). Please provide a sample implementation and I will mark your answer correct. Thanks nonetheless for the input.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use `Contract.Assume` when the static checker isn't able to verify an expression.

You'll end up with a lot of places where you have to use `Contract.Assume` if you're trying to get to zero static checker warnings unless your program is trivial because most of the .Net libraries don't yet have contracts so I wouldn't worry about it. Most of the time having clear code and a good set of unit tests is better than having zero contract warnings. That said, leave squigglies on so you can verify that the warnings are a false positive when you're coding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a possibility to violate the contract. Remeber that `IndexOf` and `EndsWith` by default use culture-specific comparison, which sometimes might have surprising behavior. If I write

```
TrimAfter("\u0301a\u0301a", "\u0301a")
```

then `IndexOf` does not match the first occurence, because it considers the middle characters to be a single `'á'`, so `index` is `2` and the method returns `"\u0301a"`, which obviously ends with the suffix.

If you want provably correct algorithms, use `StringComparison.Ordinal`.

However, the Code Contracts static checker currently does not support analysis of string values, and does not understand this relation between `IndexOf` and `Substring`.